# Is it time to prune this Chrysanthemum?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, pruning

For some reason, the bottom of the body of my Chrysanthemum is dying (probably root rot?):

[image]

Using the arrows, I have tried to show that for the middle part, it is dead on one side. Of course I can wait, and see if it heals or dies completely, but I prefer to ask questions and hope there is anything I can do to save my Chrysanthemum:

1. Is this a disease?
2. Shall I cut the upper part, trim some leaves, and stick it in some soil?

Answer (score 3):

I was puzzled by the picture at first, the leaves looked a bit thick and fleshy and less deeply lobed than the Chrysanthemums I am accustomed to, but likely this is just *Chrysanthemum X Morifolium* / *Dendranthemum* or the Florist's Chrysanthemum.

I think I would catch the wave of the upcoming spring with this guy; allow the plant to keep growing vegetatively for a few more weeks (if you are in N. hemisphere) and catch the warmth and light of spring by taking cuttings from this plant and start them off well following @stormy advice. Choose your cutting points carefully to leave the plant able to recover and send out more shoots, so it acts as a backup. Then once your new cuttings become magnificent you can toss the old one, with thanks.

Comment: So if i understood, this plant can make it until the beginning of the spring ?

Comment: Well, apart from the sad piece on the left, the rest of it looks turgid (nicely pumped up with moisture, not droopy) and your cuts look clean and sharp and smooth, so I would give it a go and leave it till spring. The pot is a bit big, but I would personally leave it as is and see how it goes, with respectful attention to other opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Too small of a plant for the size of pot. If that is not sterilized potting soil that is part of the problem.  Get a pot 1/4 that size, cut off the dead branch, use only sterilized potting soil, pot with hole on bottom, no rocks or gravel below soil and water only when the pot is light.  Lots of bright light but no direct light...unless this is an outdoor plant used to full sunlight.  Forget fertilizer until this plant gets settled.  Then just get Osmocote 14-14-14, and use only twice a year!  Follow directions.  Is this garden soil or potting soil?  This is too big of a pot for such a small plant.  That will cause root rot.

Comment: I assume any comercial soil is sterilized. Isn't that the case ?

Comment: Not for construction and in bulk.  Just the bagged stuff and NOT anything that says 'topsoil'.  Don't get any water holding sponges or fertilizer added!!  I always use the cheapest soil but if I find fungus growing I'll change brands.  I now use more expensive stuff with less vermiculite, no peat moss and has mycorrhizae and certain bacteria added.  'Compost' is not potting soil.

Comment: Too large of a pot to too small of a plant is a deal breaker.  Not enough roots to help drain the soil of water.  In the nursery world, it isn't unusual to have 6 or 7 'up pots'.  Healthier plant, far more success.  People think that growing stuff in pots is like growing stuff in the garden soil.  Boy, there is a huge difference.  And your...plant is on the succulent side with fleshy leaves that hold water...I'd get a 6" pot no larger. Fill with potting soil 1/3 then turn your pot and plant upside down over newspaper, allow extra soil to fall, flip it over and plant in 6" pot. Firm soil...h2o